# Implementing Financial Force Lib built-in trigger recursion handling?

Tags: apex, trigger, financialforce

I'm looking at implementing the fflib_DomainClass in an org as our trigger handler. I know from @AndrewFawcett blog that there's a [built in means](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/06/28/financialforce-apex-common-updates/) of handling it. There's also been [discussion on Github](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common/issues/149) about the feature and alternative means of handling it. After reading the blog and the discussion, it's unclear to me what the intended way of implementing recursion control is supposed to be.

It appears that to do recursion control, one is expected to write something along the lines of:

```
fflib_SObjectDomain.getTriggerEvent(YourDomain.class).disable(SomeEvent);
```

I'm having difficulty seeing exactly how to properly use this means of control whether it's implemented in the virtual DomainClass, the Actual Trigger Handler Class or in some other control class. Is there something I'm missing? For reference, below is a stripped down version of the virtual class.

Also, you may want to make note of the section near the end of the code that follows my comments that begin with `/***`. It appears to me that's what's relevant along with the Fluent style Configuration section of code at the very end.

```
// Copyright (c) 2012, FinancialForce.com, inc
// All rights reserved.

public virtual with sharing class SObjectDomain
{
    // Provides access to the data represented by this domain class
    public List<SObject> Records { get; private set;}

    // Derived from the records provided during construction, provides the native describe for the standard or custom object
    public Schema.DescribeSObjectResult SObjectDescribe {get; private set;}

    // Exposes the configuration for this domain class instance 
    public Configuration Configuration {get; private set;}    

    // Retains instances of domain classes implementing trigger stateful
    private static Map<Type, List<SObjectDomain>> TriggerStateByClass; 

    static
    {
        TriggerStateByClass = new Map<Type, List<SObjectDomain>>();
    }

    // Constructs the domain class with the data on which to apply the behaviour implemented within
    public SObjectDomain(List<SObject> sObjectList)
    {
        // Ensure the domain class has its own copy of the data
        Records = sObjectList.clone(); 
        // Capture SObjectType describe for this domain class
        SObjectDescribe = Records.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
        // Configure the Domain object instance 
        Configuration = new Configuration();        
    }

    // Override this to perform processing during the before insert phase, this is called by the handleBeforeInsert method
    public virtual void onBeforeInsert() { }

    // Override this to perform processing during the before update phase, this is called by the handleBeforeUpdate method
    public virtual void onBeforeUpdate(Map<Id,SObject> existingRecords) { }

    // Override this to perform processing during the before delete phase, this is called by the handleBeforeDelete method 
    public virtual void onBeforeDelete() { }

    // Override this to perform processing during the after insert phase, this is called by the handleAfterInsert method
    public virtual void onAfterInsert() { }

    // Override this to perform processing during the after update phase, this is called by the handleAfterUpdate method    
    public virtual void onAfterUpdate(Map<Id,SObject> existingRecords) { }

    // Override this to perform processing during the after delete phase, this is called by the handleAfterDelete method    
    public virtual void onAfterDelete() { } 

    // Base handler for the Apex Trigger event Before Insert, calls onBeforeInsert
    public virtual void handleBeforeInsert() 
    { 
        onBeforeInsert();
    }

    // Base handler for the Apex Trigger event Before Update, calls the onBeforeUpdate method
    public void handleBeforeUpdate(Map<Id,SObject> existingRecords) 
    {
        onBeforeUpdate(existingRecords);
    }

    // Base handler for the Apex Trigger event Before Delete, calls the onBeforeDelete method
    public void handleBeforeDelete() 
    {
        onBeforeDelete();
    }

    // Base handler for the Apex Trigger event After Insert, calls the onAfterInsert methods
    public void handleAfterInsert()
    {
        onAfterInsert(); 
    }

    // Calls onAfterUpdate methods
    public void handleAfterUpdate(Map<Id,SObject> existingRecords) 
    {       

        onAfterUpdate(existingRecords); 
    }

    // Base handler for the Apex Trigger event After Delete, checks object security and calls the onAfterDelete method
    public void handleAfterDelete() 
    {
        onAfterDelete();
    }   

     // Interface used to aid the triggerHandler in constructing instances of Domain classes
    public interface IConstructable
    {
        SObjectDomain construct(List<SObject> sObjectList);
    }

    // For Domain classes implementing the ITriggerStateful interface returns the instance 
    // of the domain class being shared between trigger invocations, returns null if
    // the Domain class trigger has not yet fired or the given domain class does not implement
    // the ITriggerStateful interface. Note this method is sensitive to recursion, meaning
    // it will return the applicable domain instance for the level of recursion

    /*** What's below would seem to affect recursion control ***/
    public static SObjectDomain getTriggerInstance(Type domainClass)
    {
        List<SObjectDomain> domains = TriggerStateByClass.get(domainClass);
        if(domains==null || domains.size()==0)
            return null;
        return domains[domains.size()-1];
    }

    // Method constructs the given Domain class with the current Trigger context 
    // before calling the applicable override methods such as beforeInsert, beforeUpdate etc.
    public static void triggerHandler(Type domainClass)
    {       
        // Process the trigger context
        if(System.Test.isRunningTest() & Test.Database.hasRecords())
        {
            // If in test context and records in the mock database delegate initially to the mock database trigger handler
            Test.Database.testTriggerHandler(domainClass);
        }
        else
        {
            // Process the runtime Apex Trigger context 
            triggerHandler(domainClass, 
                Trigger.isBefore, 
                Trigger.isAfter, 
                Trigger.isInsert, 
                Trigger.isUpdate, 
                Trigger.isDelete, 
                Trigger.new, 
                Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }

     // Calls the applicable override methods such as beforeInsert, beforeUpdate etc. based on a Trigger context
    private static void triggerHandler(Type domainClass, Boolean isBefore, Boolean isAfter, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isDelete, List<SObject> newRecords, Map<Id, SObject> oldRecordsMap)
    {   
        // After phase of trigger will reuse prior instance of domain class if ITriggerStateful implemented 
        SObjectDomain domainObject = isBefore ? null : popTriggerInstance(domainClass, isDelete ? oldRecordsMap.values() : newRecords);
        if(domainObject==null)
        {       
            // Construct the domain class constructor class
            String domainClassName = domainClass.getName();
            Type constructableClass = domainClassName.endsWith('Constructor') ? Type.forName(domainClassName) : Type.forName(domainClassName+'.Constructor');
            IConstructable domainConstructor = (IConstructable) constructableClass.newInstance();

            // Construct the domain class with the approprite record set        
            if(isInsert) domainObject = domainConstructor.construct(newRecords);
            else if(isUpdate) domainObject = domainConstructor.construct(newRecords);
            else if(isDelete) domainObject = domainConstructor.construct(oldRecordsMap.values());

            // Should this instance be reused on the next trigger invocation?
            if(domainObject.Configuration.TriggerStateEnabled)
                // Push this instance onto the stack to be popped during the after phase
                pushTriggerInstance(domainClass, domainObject); 
        }

        // Invoke the applicable handler
        if(isBefore)
        {
            if(isInsert) domainObject.handleBeforeInsert();
            else if(isUpdate) domainObject.handleBeforeUpdate(oldRecordsMap);
            else if(isDelete) domainObject.handleBeforeDelete();
        }
        else
        {
            if(isInsert) domainObject.handleAfterInsert();
            else if(isUpdate) domainObject.handleAfterUpdate(oldRecordsMap);
            else if(isDelete) domainObject.handleAfterDelete();
        }               
    }

    // Pushes to the stack of domain classes per type a domain object instance
    private static void pushTriggerInstance(Type domainClass, SObjectDomain domain)
    {
        List<SObjectDomain> domains = TriggerStateByClass.get(domainClass);
        if(domains==null)
            TriggerStateByClass.put(domainClass, domains = new List<SObjectDomain>());
        domains.add(domain);        
    }

    // Pops from the stack of domain classes per type a domain object instance and updates the record set
    private static SObjectDomain popTriggerInstance(Type domainClass, List<SObject> records)
    {
        List<SObjectDomain> domains = TriggerStateByClass.get(domainClass);
        if(domains==null || domains.size()==0)
            return null;        
        SObjectDomain domain = domains.remove(domains.size()-1);
        domain.Records = records;
        return domain;
    }

    // Fluent style Configuration system for Domain class creation
    public class Configuration
    {
        // Enables reuse of the same Domain instance between before and after trigger phases (subject to recursive scenarios)
        public Boolean TriggerStateEnabled {get; private set;}

        // Default configuration 
        public Configuration()
        {
            TriggerStateEnabled = true;
        }

        // See associated property
        public Configuration enableTriggerState()
        {
            TriggerStateEnabled = true;
            return this;    
        }

        // See associated property
        public Configuration disableTriggerState()
        {
            TriggerStateEnabled = false;
            return this;    
        }
    }
}
```